# Looping array error again :(

Tags: php, arrays, yii

//i want to loop an array to make dinamic chart

//form this

```
$this->widget('ext.Hzl.google.HzlVisualizationChart', array('visualization' => 'LineChart',
            'data' => array(
                0=>array('Task', 'Hours per Day'),
                1=>array('Work', 11),
               2=>array('Work', 11),
            ),
            'options' => array('title' => 'My Daily Activity')));
        ?>
```

//to

```
$a=0;
$loop=array();
while ($a < 10)
{
$loop=$loop+array("a","1");
$a=$a+1;
}
   $this->widget('ext.Hzl.google.HzlVisualizationChart', array('visualization' => 'LineChart',
            'data' => $loop
            'options' => array('title' => 'My Daily Activity')));
        ?>
```

//but this code is error, please help me :(

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want `$loop` to be an array similar to the first example.

You need to change this:

```
$loop=$loop+array("a","1");
```

to this:

```
$loop[] = array("a","1");
```

This will add a new element to the array instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`$loop[] = array("a","1");` to add elements to the existing array.

And you are missing a comma after the `'data' => $loop`

Try using:

```
$a=0;
$loop=array();
while ($a < 10)
{
$loop[] = array("a","1"); // "a" or $a ?
$a=$a+1;
}
   $this->widget('ext.Hzl.google.HzlVisualizationChart', array('visualization' => 'LineChart',
            'data' => $loop,
            'options' => array('title' => 'My Daily Activity')));
        ?>
```